# CMake: How to get subdirectories to use source files from the root directory

Tags: cmake

I have this variable set in the root CMakeLists.txt

```
set(${LIBNAME}_srcs
File1.cpp
File2.cpp
File3.cpp
File4.cpp
File5.cpp
)
add_subdirectory(A)
```

and I want to add the variable as a source for the executable in the subdirectory A

```
add_executable(${TEST}}
```

What is the cleanest way to do this? without having to create a new variable with ../ on all the source files? Or is there a macro I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the absolute path to each of the values in `${LIBNAME}_srcs` by doing something like:

```
foreach(${LIBNAME}_src ${${LIBNAME}_srcs})
  list(APPEND abs_${LIBNAME}_srcs ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${${LIBNAME}_src})
endforeach()

add_executable(${TEST} ${abs_${LIBNAME}_srcs})
```

Jumping to conclusions here, it looks like what you're doing may be a bit unusual.

Normally the `add_executable` call would be made in the same place where the list of source files is gathered - usually in the same directory.

Going by the fact that you've named your sources variable `${LIBNAME}_srcs`, I'd guess that you're already creating a library from these sources.  If so, it'd be better to just link that library in your test subdirectory rather than recompiling all the library's sources into the executable.

Something like:

```
add_executable(${TEST} test_main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${TEST} ${LIBNAME})
```

Answer (score 0):

When I add sources, I do something like this:

```
set(${LIBNAME}_srcs
${SRC}/File1.cpp
${SRC}/File2.cpp
${SRC}/File3.cpp
${SRC}/File4.cpp
${SRC}/File5.cpp
)
```

Where `${SRC}` is the absolute path to the source directory found using `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Then, you can simply use `add_executable(${TEST} ${LIBNAME}_srcs)` in your subdirectory.  CMake will automatically import the scope of parent directories into child directories.